# How to add data retrieved from database to previously set dynamic markers based on the onclick location android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I am trying to add data which is retrieved from my database to a custom dialog I have created. After an `onclick` within the Google Maps interface the expected result will show the data specific to the location of the marker selected. The data is different for each location.

The `OnPostExecte` method of the `backgroundhelper` class is below.

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray beachlists) {
            if (beachlists != null) {
                try {

                    for(int i = 0; i < beachlists.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject beaches = beachlists.getJSONObject(i);

                        String beachname = beaches.getString("beachname");
                        double latitude = beaches.getDouble("latitude");
                        double longitude = beaches.getDouble("longitude");
                        String address = beaches.getString("address");
                        String shade = beaches.getString("shade");
                        String additionalinfo = beaches.getString("additionalinfo");

                        LatLng newbeachespoints = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                       Marker customDialogMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newbeachespoints).title(beachname));
                       customDialogMarker.setTag(beaches);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

The main activity marker on click method within my mainactivity class

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
       //Add Dynamic Data to dialog -> title, shade, additional info etc
        return false;
    }
//^^ Dynamic database element to be added

    public void showBeachDialog(Activity activity,String titlemsg, String addressmsg, String latlngmsg, String shademsg, String additionalmsg, String conditionsmsg, String uvmsg) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_beachinformation);

        TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvbeachlocationtitle);
        title.setText(titlemsg);


        TextView address = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvBeachActivitySummary1);
        address.setText(addressmsg);

        TextView latlng = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvBeachActivitySummary2);
        latlng.setText(latlngmsg);

        TextView shade = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvBeachActivitySummary3);
        shade.setText(shademsg);

        TextView additional = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvBeachActivitySummary4);
        additional.setText(additionalmsg);

        TextView conditions = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvBeachActivitySummary5);
        conditions.setText(conditionsmsg);

        TextView uv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvBeachActivitySummary6);
        uv.setText(uvmsg);


        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialogClothingActivity);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Any ideas?

Unsure as to how to get the data to populate dynamically

Comment: Seems like you are nearly there - you add a `JSONObject` as the tag of the marker.  So in the `onMarkerClick` use the `marker.getTag()` to get that same object and extract the necessary parameters from the JSON to populate the parameters.  Note it seems you may want to implement a custom InfoWindow instead as your dialog just displays marker information?